# WL.Client.setUserPref is not working in windows 8/8.1 device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

WL.Client.setUserPref is not working on Windows device only but on android BB iOS it is working fine.
We are using MobileFirst 6.3 and same code, any idea why it is not working ?

Comment: In what way is the API failing?  Do you have an "onFailure" callback defined when you call WL.Client.setUserPref?  If so, is the onFailure callback being invoked in this case, and what error code is being given?

Comment: There is no callback defined it is WL.Client.setUserpref('fav','foo')

Comment: Provide your code. Did you also check in the Windows 8 Emulator - does it fail there as well or only in a device? Please verify.

Comment: on click event of a button WL.Client.setUserPref("xxx",xxx); and on app startup WL.Client.connect({onSuccess:onSuccessCallback}); and onSuccessCallback we call WL.Client.getUserPref("xxx"); it is working fine in all enviornment except windows

Comment: Please read my question again - does it fail only in device or also in emulator, in Windows 8.

Comment: checked on device only. WL.Client.setuserpref("xxx",xxx,{onSuccess:function(){},onFailure:.....}) onSuccesscallback  is being called did not raise onFailure and onclick just after setuserpref  if I do getUserPref i can see the userpref, but on application startup inside WL.connect getUserPref is giving null value

Answer (score 0):

I checked this issue and it is really a defect. 
Please open a PMR (support ticket) to IBM about this issue.

There is no local workaround.